# Why use a cookie rather than logging in each transaction

Tags: java, spring, authentication, session, cookies

Using Spring Boot in Java to consume REST calls. The server allows me to log in, and returns a session cookie.

Is there a good reason to use the session cookie as opposed to logging in each time?

Answer (score 0):

Because logging in each time a call is made requires more time and more communication between client and server.

Logging in process

1) Client send login request.

2) Server responds with success message (or failure message)

3) Client sends actual request

4) Server sends result

With session cookie assuming login has already occurred

1) Client sends request with cookie

2) Server checks cookie and sends result

So basically using a cookie saves you time.

Comment: Well actually no it doesn't work like that and it actually depends on the authentication mechanism being used. When using something like BASIC or TOKEN authentication you can simply send that as part of each request and it will act just like it does with a cookie, but with the overhead of doing authentication each time.

Answer (score 0):

A cookie is always necessary if you are stateful to continue the conversation.

It abstract and cache the identification of the client and other attributes you may want to keep accross requests.

So it is mostly a cache. As a cache, it means the user doesn't need to send his credential each time, you don't have to authenticate him each time and you can use the user session as a place holder for temporary data.

In exchange of this conveniance, you get drawbacks. This make it harder to scale because you need to share this state and keep it consistant on the server side. It also become easier to trick the server into thinking that the request is legitimate while it is not.